# Swift iOS -How To Sort An Array In A Specific Order?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of strings that I pull from the web in any assortment of colors:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "purple"]
```

but it also might come as:

```
//this time less colors
var colors = ["yellow", "red", "purple"]
```

No matter which way they come in I want to sort through the colors array and add them to a new array and I want the new array to have this order:

```
//the way I want the new array to have it's elements
["red", "purple", "pink", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "orange", "green"]
```

I tried:

```
var newArr:[String] = []

for color in colors{

  if color == "red"{
    newArr[0] = "red"
  }
  if color == "purple"{
    newArr[1] = "purple"
  }
  if color == "pink"{
    newArr[2] = "pink"
  }
  if color == "yellow"{
    newArr[3] = "yellow"
  }
  if color == "brown"{
    newArr[4] = "brown"
  }
  if color == "blue"{
    newArr[5] = "blue"
  }
  if color == "orange"{
    newArr[6] = "orange"
  }
  if color == "green"{
    newArr[7] = "green"
  }
}
```

I got an exception:

> fatal error: Index out of range

I know where I made the out of range mistake at but I can't figure out how to get it to put it in the order I want.

How can I loop through the colors array and take whatever elements are inside of it and add them to a new array in the order I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution - filter the master list of colors based on the colors you actually have.

```
let masterColors = ["red", "purple", "pink", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "orange", "green"]
var colors = ["yellow", "red", "purple"] // whatever colors you have
var newArr = masterColors.filter { colors.contains($0) }
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm going to try it in 15 min and let you know.

Comment: as per your usual assitance! It works :)